# integration of deadbolt with play framework 2.5

Tags: java, web, playframework, typesafe-activator

[image for error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpKTW.png) after adding `"be.objectify" %% "deadbolt-java" % "2.4.3"` in `built.sbt` file in over play project  and than in `application.conf` file adding :

```
play {
  modules {
    enabled += be.objectify.deadbolt.java.DeadboltModule
  }
}
```

and than when i am implementing HandlerCache it says can not resolve HandlerCache. and giving the following error shows in image while running the project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose your handlers to Deadbolt.Create a module that binds your handler cache and add it in application.conf

Sample new module:

```
    public class SecurityHook extends Module{

    @Override
    public Seq<Binding<?>> bindings(Environment environment, Configuration configuration) {
        return seq(bind(DeadboltHandler.class).to(SecurityHandler.class).in(Singleton.class),
                    bind(HandlerCache.class).to(SecurityHandlerCache.class).in(Singleton.class));
    }
}
```

application.conf:

```
play.modules {
  enabled += be.objectify.deadbolt.java.DeadboltModule
  enabled += security.SecurityHook
}
```